# How to use TPM2.0 on laptop to store data

Tags: linux, windows, save, tpm

I have tried to learn about the commands about using tpm on Linux and Windows, but I still can't find a way to save personal data to my tpm2.0 chip.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Which tools are you using tpm2-tools, tools from ibmtss,....? You can not store much data inside the tpm, you can store a key and encrypt the data with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can store a very limited amount of bytes in the nonvolatile (NV) memory of the TPM. The TPM commands to pull that off are `TPM2_NV_DefineSpace`, `TPM2_NV_Write` and `TPM2_NV_Read`.

What you usually want to do is store data on your hard disk, encrypted by a key which is protected by your TPM. Have a look at the [TPM-js learning tool](https://google.github.io/tpm-js/#pg_keys) by Google for more information how that works.

With regard to the implementation, there are several tools to make your life easier. The [tpm2-tss](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tss) is a C library, the highest level API is the FAPI (Feature API). There are also several wrappers for other languages. If you want to use executables in a shell, I recommend the [tpm2-tools](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools).